# Alter view when detail view pushed iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view with a custom bar at the bottom of the screen. When a collection view cell is pressed, it loads a detail view, and I can go back.

This all works great; however, I have a plus button displayed on the custom bar, and I would like for the plus button to disappear only when the detail view shows up, and then come back when you hit the back button.

So far I have used the delegate method:

```
    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Your code to update the parent view

}
```

The problem is this fires when the detail view is loaded and popped as well. Any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `mainView` and `detailView` are `viewControllers`. In `mainView's viewWillAppear` method

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   //get reference of plus button here
   btnPlus.hidden = NO;
}
```

In `detailView's viewWillAppear` method

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   //get reference of plus button here
   btnPlus.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: At first this did not work, until I realized that I was adding the custom bar view to the navigation controller instead of the view controller. After fixing this, your method worked great! Gotta love the really simple solutions that you just dont see after hours of staring at code! Thanks a lot!